# merge changes on detached branch after git checkout <commit hash>

Tags: git, github

I was originally working on git branch named "`feature`". Then ，I commited my changes .

Then I noticed there are some new created files shouldn't be in my commit. So I found the **lastest commit hash** `1b33aa` (I use `git log` command).

After that, I did:

```
git checkout 1b63aa
```

Then I made more changes (I though I was still on feature branch...my mistake), and commited again.

Then I run `git branch` ,it prints out :

```
* (detached from 1b33aa)
  feature
```

How can I merge back those changes I just made to `feature` branch now?

Comment: What do you mean by the "latest commit hash"? Do you mean the commit that `HEAD` was pointing to?

Comment: Can you `git cherry-pick` the commits into your feature branch?

Comment: Yes， I mean the changes I just made

Comment: @Leem.fin Was that reply directed at me? If so, I'm confused as to how checking out `HEAD` would help your problem of "some new created files shouldn't be in my commit".

Could you post the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate HEAD feature` so I can see exactly what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on a detached branch now. It seems you want to replace your `feature` branch with this one. A safe way to do that is to rename `feature` to something else and then turn the current branch into a proper branch named `feature`:

```
git branch -m feature feature-bak
git checkout -b feature
```

In your first step, I think you wanted to do a `git reset` instead of a `git checkout`:

```
git reset 1b63aa
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to replace the `feature` branch but merge the changes in the current branch to `feature`, you can do like this:

```
git checkout -b temp
git checkout feature
git merge temp
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what it sounded like to me also. The question "How can I merge back those changes I just made to feature branch now?" made me question that interpretation though.

Comment: I added an answer for that part too, just to be safe ;-)